# How to pre-process the request body in Spring before passing it to the a Controller?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servlet-filters

I am implementing a RESTful service and I would like to validate the XML against an XSD in an interceptor before passing it on the a `CastorUnmarshaller`. 
Though, in the `WebRequestInterceptor` I have to read the request body which can only be read once so the unmarshaller cannot read it. Is there a way of doing it?

I know that I can do both the validation and the unmarshalling manually in the Controller, but I would like to use the `@RequestBody <DomainObject>` way to unmarhall it.

Alternatively, as another solution, is there a way to tell the `CastorUnmarshaller` to validate it against the xsd?

Answer (score 5):

Quite a long time passed, but someone else might benefit from this:

You can define an @Around aspect and intercept the incoming requests and their respective bodies as follows:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class RequestResponseLoggingAdvice {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestResponseLoggingAdvice.class);

    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController*)") 
    public void restcontroller() {}

    @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping)") 
    public void postmapping() {}

    @Around("restcontroller() && postmapping() && args(.., @RequestBody body, request)") 
    public Object logPostMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Object body, HttpServletRequest request) throws Throwable {
        logger.debug(request.toString()); // You may log request parameters here.
        logger.debug(body.toString()); // You may do some reflection here

        Object result;
        try {
            result = joinPoint.proceed();
            logger.debug(result.toString());
        } catch(Throwable t) {}
    }
}
```

Please note that your REST controller methods have to have suitable signatures for the above aspect can hook in. A sample one could be as follows:

```
@PostMapping
public SampleDTO saveSample(@RequestBody Sample sample, HttpServletRequest request) { 
    //.....
}
```

Comment: Thank you man! I didn't know that I can obtain @RequestBody just specifiying it in pointcut,

Answer (score 0):

You can probably attach a `@Before` aspect (spring AOP). There you can get the same request body parameter as passed to the controller method.

Another option is to wrap the request into one that supports reading the body multiple times (by caching it the first time)

Answer (score 0):

A filter can also be used to validate the XML passed.
**org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller** has a **validating** property to enable validation on in- and out-going documents.
But enabling it in Spring-MVC's default marshaller must be solved.